# Appium Fails to launch app sometimes

Tags: appium

If I execute appium scripts over some time period say half an hr and during the execution I have called `driver.closeApp();  & driver.launchApp();` 
sometimes `driver.launchApp();` fails saying `Unable to launch the app: Error: Trying to start logcat capture but it's already started! (WARNING: The server did not provide any stack trace information)`

Temporarily I am handling this using try catch block like

```
try{
    -- openApp;
}catch(Exception e){
    -- openApp;
}
```

Is there any better way to make sure App is Up and running ?

Comment: version of appium/java client used?

Comment: Yes, just use any locator of your app and verify if this element is present, don't open the app otherwise launchApp();

Comment: just wondering why you use driver.closeApp() then driver.openApp(). I can see why if you have to do something in between these actions, but would driver.resetApp() be more useful to you?

Comment: New test case should start with Open app and should end with close app.. So if some test case fails or app crashes, next test case will open a fresh copy of app.. Thats why using close App at the end of each test case and Open app before starting a new test case.

Comment: @nullpointer appium- 1.4.16.1 library is up to date :)

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks for your point. I tried with get current activity.. It works. But I was wondering why appium fails.. It should retry opening an app   the way I am doing.

Comment: i faced this before. logcat, appium server, uiaoutomator all uses the same session id, the session id becomes stale at times in logcat or uiautomator. if you close ui automator and run scripts it works fine